# Duvida em um programa simples de CRIPTOGRAFIA em c++

Tags: c++

estou com uma duvida para implementar um código de criptografia.
Segue o código a baixo:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    string criptografar(string mensagem);
    string descriptografar(string mensagem);
    string mens_original;
    string mens_criptografada;
    string mens_descriptografada;
    mens_original = "A";

    cout<< "Mensagem original: "<< mens_original << endl;

    mens_criptografada = criptografar(mens_original);
    cout << "Mensagem criptografada: " << mens_criptografada << endl;

    mens_descriptografada = descriptografar(mens_criptografada);
    cout << "Mensagem descriptografada: " << mens_descriptografada << endl;

    return 0;
}

string criptografar(string mensagem)
{
    int tamanho = 0;
    tamanho = mensagem.length();

    for (int i = 0 ; i < tamanho; i++)
    {

        mensagem[i] = (int) mensagem[i] * 2 ;

    }



    return mensagem;
}

string descriptografar(string mensagem)
{
    int tamanho = 0;
    tamanho = mensagem.length();


    for (int i = 0 ; i < tamanho ; i++)
    {

        mensagem[i] = (int) mensagem [i] / 2;


    }


    return mensagem;
}
```

Bom, quando colocamos o seguinte:

```
    mensagem[i] = (int) mensagem[i] + 2 //criptografar;


    mensagem[i] = (int) mensagem[i] - 2 // descriptografar;
```

O programa roda, faz os calculos e nos retorna o novo valor (criptografia) da letra "A", que no caso vai para "Ç", e na hora de descriptografar o valor retorna para "A".

Já se fizermos:

```
    mensagem[i] = (int) mensagem[i] * 2 //criptografar;


    mensagem[i] = (int) mensagem[i] / 2 // descriptografar;
```

O valor de "A" vai para "é" normal (2*65 = 130 -> valor de "é") mas na hora de 
descriptografar ate 1 momento antes do laço FOR da função  descriptografar  o valor de 'mensagem' = "é" que é o que nos queremos, mas ao entrar para o laço o valor assume um outro valor (negativo) e acaba resultando em outro caractere da tabela ASCII, e ao verificar o valor de 'mensagem[i]' = (valor negativo). claro por que se mensagem[i] assumiu um valor negativo qualquer o resultado, no fim teria que ser negativo.

Minha pergunta é: Por que isso ta acontecendo?
Se vocês tiverem soluções por favor me ajudem!
OBS: Já verifiquei os valores da tabela ASCII para ver se estava extrapolando ao fazer a multiplicação, mas não é o caso.

Answer (score 1):

Esse algoritmo de "criptografia" apresentado se trata da [`Cifra de César`](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cifra_de_C%C3%A9sar), e é um das mais simples e conhecidas técnicas de criptografia existentes.

É um tipo de cifra de substituição na qual cada letra do texto é substituída por outra.

A cifragem da letra `x` usando um deslocamento `n` pode ser escrito matematicamente como:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A decifragem é feita de forma parecida:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para `n=1`, a tabela de substituição seria algo como:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Onde a cifragem do texto `OLA MUNDO!` seria:

```
PMB NVOEP!
```

Segue uma implementação em `C++` capaz de cifrar e decifrar uma string usando a [`Cifra de César`](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cifra_de_C%C3%A9sar):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

char converter(char ch, int chave)
{
    if (!isalpha(ch)) return ch;
    char offset = isupper(ch) ? 'A' : 'a';
    return (char)((((ch + chave) - offset) % 26) + offset);
}

string criptografar( string entrada, int chave )
{
    string saida = "";
    size_t len = entrada.size();
    for( size_t i = 0; i < len; i++ )
        saida += converter( entrada[i], chave );
    return saida;
}

string decriptografar( string entrada, int chave )
{
    return criptografar( entrada, 26 - chave );
}

int main( void )
{
    int chave = 13;

    string txt = "O rato roeu a roupa do rei de Roma!";
    cout << "Texto Original: " << txt << endl;

    string cripto = criptografar( txt, chave );
    cout << "Texto Cifrado: " << cripto << endl;

    string decripto = decriptografar( cripto, chave );
    cout << "Texto Decifrado: " << decripto << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Saída (`chave=13`):

```
Texto Original: O rato roeu a roupa do rei de Roma!
Texto Cifrado: B engb ebrh n ebhcn qb erv qr Ebzn!
Texto Decifrado: O rato roeu a roupa do rei de Roma!
```

Saída (`chave=7`):

```
Texto Original: O rato roeu a roupa do rei de Roma!
Texto Cifrado: V yhav yvlb h yvbwh kv ylp kl Yvth!
Texto Decifrado: O rato roeu a roupa do rei de Roma!
```

Saída (`chave=1`):

```
Texto Original: O rato roeu a roupa do rei de Roma!
Texto Cifrado: P sbup spfv b spvqb ep sfj ef Spnb!
Texto Decifrado: O rato roeu a roupa do rei de Roma!
```

Answer (score 0):

O problema relatado acontece porque o tipo "char" está sendo considerado como "signed char", o que é normal, mas quando uma variável "signed char" é convertida para int o valor pode ser ser negativo, caso o codepoint do caracter seja maior que 127.

Para resolver este problema, ao converter de "char" para "int" pode-se usar um cast explícito para "unsigned char".

Exemplo

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  string x = "é";

  cout << "* char: " << int(x[0]) << '\n';
  cout << "* unsigned char: " << int((unsigned char)(x[0])) << '\n';
}
```

Saída:

```
D:\projects\misc
$ teste.exe
* char: -23
* unsigned char: 233

D:\projects\misc
$
```